# A query on git HEAD

Tags: git

I am asking this question to understand implementation details of git, so I may be wrong in technical terms.

Going through git scm book, I understand that HEAD can point to a branch(which itself is a pointer to a commit). and also to a commit.

So HEAD can point to two objects of different types.

Is it possible for a pointer to point to objects of diff types(commit and branch dont seem to be connected in terms of hierarchy)?

Comment: git always reference to commit. For branch it is a reference to the last commit of this branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In technical but totally-concrete terms, `HEAD` is actually a file, `.git/HEAD`.  It contains either:

- the name of a branch, or
- the hash ID of a commit.

When `HEAD` contains the hash ID of a commit, that's all it has.  Git calls this situation a *detached HEAD* and the only information available is the commit's hash ID.

When `HEAD` contains the name of a branch, though, now you have two ways to ask Git about it:

- *Hey, Git, tell me what hash ID `HEAD` names.*  Git looks at `HEAD`, sees that it names `master`, then looks at `master` to see what hash ID `master` names.  That's the answer to your question.
- Or, *Hey, Git, tell me what branch `HEAD` names.*  Git looks at `HEAD`, sees that it names `master`, and tells you `master` as the answer to your question.

Every *branch name* always contains the hash ID of exactly one commit, so if `HEAD` contains a branch name, Git can always do the `HEAD`-to-hash-ID thing by doing the two steps.  When `HEAD` contains a raw hash ID, though, an attempt to ask Git what branch name it holds gives you an error:

```
$ git checkout --detach master
HEAD is now at 83232e3864 The seventh batch
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD
fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref
```

or, using `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name`, just prints `HEAD`:

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD
HEAD
```

Re-attaching `HEAD` to `master` makes these both produce branch names:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD
refs/heads/master
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD
refs/heads/master
```

So that's how `HEAD` can be either a branch name or a commit hash, except when it can only be a commit hash.